# undefined method `item_id' for @order.save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, nomethoderror

I'm creating a rails app with relational DB, when I try to save order appearing NoMethodError to string that I pass to order.new
I'm new to rails and maybe don`t fully understand how need to proceed with the records. But debugger cant show me where to search for errors.

controller

```
class OrdersController

  def create
    #render plain: params
    a = {amount: params[:amount], user_id: current_user.id, id: 1}
    @order = Order.new a

    a = {quantity: params[:quantity], item_id: params[:item], order_id: 1}
    @order_description = OrderDescription.new a
    @order.save
    @order_description.save
  end
```

error

```
undefined method `item_id' for #<Order id: 1, amount: 2222, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 19>
```

db

```
  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "order_descriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "item_id", null: false
    t.bigint "order_id", null: false
    t.index ["item_id"], name: "index_order_descriptions_on_item_id"
    t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_order_descriptions_on_order_id"
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "amount"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_orders_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "order_descriptions", "items"
  add_foreign_key "order_descriptions", "orders"
  add_foreign_key "orders", "users"
```

I tried to remove the relations in the ruby model but not help. This error happens regardless of the data I pass to it.

**True Solve**

In folder test/fixters I found a file named order.yml and in it was field item_id (God know how it appears there) and because of these field order.save doesn't pass the validation test.

Comment: This controller is broken in many ways. You're assigning the orders the fixed id 1 which will break after the first order is created since primary keys must be unique. You're also not checking if anything is actually saved and `@order_description.save` depends on the order actually being saved. As for the error itself - its not explained by the code in provided here and is probally caused by the model or view. I would start with the rails guides on assocations and work your way forward as you might be taking on a task thats beyond your  skill level.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: yeah, I know that I was busy trying to get rid of my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to setup a `has_many through:` association. Where `order_descriptions` serves as the *line items* of an order.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_descriptions
  has_many :items, through: :order_descriptions
end

# very vague name - you could do better
class OrderDescription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :order
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_descriptions
  has_many :orders, through: :order_descriptions
end
```

If you want to create an classical order form where you create an order with multiple lines you can use `accepts_nested_attributes`:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_descriptions
  has_many :items, through: :order_descriptions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_descriptions, reject_if: :all_blank?
end
```

This lets you pass an array of attributes (hashes) to create the parent and child records at the same time:

```
Order.create(
  user: User.first,
  order_descriptions_attributes: [
    { item_id: 1, quantity: 10 },
    { item_id: 2, quantity: 20 }
  ]
)
```

You can handle this in a form with `fields_for`:

```
<%= form_with(model: @order) do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for(:order_descriptions) do |ff| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.label :item_id %>
      <%= ff.collection_select :item_id, @items, :id, :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.label :quantity %>
      <%= ff.number_field :quantity, step: 1 %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And in your controller with:

```
class OrdersController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
  end

  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @items = Item.all
    5.times { @order.order_descriptions.new } 
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params) do |order|
      order.user = current_user
    end
    if @order.save
      redirect_to @order 
    else
      @items = Item.all
      5.times { @order.order_descriptions.new } 
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_order
     @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def order_params
    params.require(:order)
          .permit(
            order_descriptions_attributes: [:id, :item_id, :quantity]
          )
  end
end
```

`order_descriptions_attributes: [:item_id, :quantity]` permits an array of hashes with the keys `:id`, `:item_id` and `:quantity`.

In terms of user experience its really far from ideal though - and for your typical web shop you'll want to create the order (or in other terms cart) upfront and then setup [a nested route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) where users add line items to the order.

Comment: Thx for the help, but I don't get where I need to put Order.create? Right in Order class?